# What happens to an jQuery ajax success callback to an unreferenced object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My understanding of JavaScript is that any unreferenced object will eventually be garbage collected.

```
var myVariable = null;

function mouseClick(){
       myVariable = new myObject();
}
```

So for instance in the above code every time the mouseClick() function is run, myVariable will reference a new instance of myObject(). With the myObject() instance that used to be referenced by myVariable still existing (For the moment), but as it is no longer referenced it will be deleted by the garbage collection. Is that the case?

My question is what happens when the unreferenced myObject() has an outstanding jQuery ajax call waiting to be returned from a server. E.g. I have created an instance of myObject() that is referenced by myVariable, and as part of the creation of this object a jQuery Ajax request has been made, and before the server has respond and the jQuery success callback has run, the mouseClick() function is run again.

My understanding is that now there are 2 instances of the myObject() object (One referenced and one not), and 2 outstanding Ajax calls. My Concern is that the success callback from the Ajax call from the now unreferenced object may be run on the new referenced myObject(). I would hope that the Ajax call from the unreferenced myObject() will run by the unreferenced myObject() and then deleted as part of the garbage collection. Is this the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not an unreferenced variable.  Assuming `myVariable` is a global variable, then the myObject reference in that variable is referenced, so it will not be garbage collected.

As for an object involved in an ajax call, as long as the ajax call is in progress, the object IS being referenced by the ajax sub-system even if your own code isn't referencing it.  Only when the ajax call completes do the internal references get cleared so it can be garbage collected.

References can also happen from function closures which often occur when there is a pending callback function.  For examqple in this code:

```
function runTimer() {
    var x = new myObject();
    setTimeout(function() {
        x.foo();
    }, 1000);
}
```

even though the runTimer() function finishes immediately, the callback given to setTimeout creates a function closure which keeps everything in that function live until the setTimeout fires.  So, even though you weren't keeping explicit references to things in this function outside the function and the function has finished executing, the setTimeout keeps those variables alive because of the function closure until the setTimeout fires.

There can also be a similar thing with ajax calls.